# Best way to read CSV file and store (array, 2darray?) and print to screen in tabular format?

Tags: java

The thing i'm hoping to do is read a csv file with 6 rows and 6 columns in it using Java. I then need to print out each row and allow the user to select 1 option. Here is what I have, I know my code chooses 1 and prints it, but I don't know how to change it from printing one random row, to printing all 6 rows. Probably in an ArrayList or 2dArray?

```
package theContest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class theContest {

    // The main() method
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        //
        String fileName = "contest.csv";
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if (!file.isFile()) {
            System.err.println("Cannot open file: " + fileName + ".");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        
        //
        int numContest = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            input.nextLine();
            numContest++;
        }
        input.close();
        System.out.println("Total of " + numContest + " contestants.");
        
        //
        int winner = 0;
        Random random = new Random();
        winner = random.nextInt(numContest) + 1;
        System.out.println("The winner is contestant number " + winner + ".");
        
        //
        String winnerDetails = "";
        input = new Scanner(file);
        for (int lineCount = 0; lineCount < winner; lineCount++) {
            winnerDetails = input.nextLine();
        }
        input.close();
        System.out.println("Winner is: " + winnerDetails);
        
        //
        String id = "";
        String name = "";
        String seats = "";
        String trans = "";
        String rate = "";
        String price = "";

        input = new Scanner(winnerDetails);
        input.useDelimiter(",");
        id = input.next();
        name = input.next();
        seats = input.next();
        trans = input.next();
        rate = input.next();
        price = input.next();
        input.close();
        System.out.println("Details are:");
        System.out.printf("%-5s : %s\n", "ID",  id);
        System.out.printf("%-5s : %s\n", "Name", name);
        System.out.printf("%-5s : %s\n", "Seating", seats};
        System.out.printf("%-5s : %s\n", "Transfer", trans};
        System.out.printf("%-5s : %s\n", "Rate", rate};
        System.out.printf("%-5s : %s\n", "Price", price};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
for (int lineCount = 0; lineCount < winner; lineCount++) {
        winnerDetails = input.nextLine();
    }
```

Your file has N rows. The above code iterates all lines, and stores the result in a single variable. In each iteration, you **overwrite** what you put there before. So, what your code does is: it reads N lines, and throws away everything prior the last row.

In other words: if you have 6 lines, and you want to print all of them ... then that all your processing needs to be "part" of a loop, too.

For example, you could turn `winnerDetails` into an **array** of String, and then put each line in its own slot. Then you loop over the array, and print each slot.

And as you already know about ArrayList, best use that then. That also means: you need to read the file only once. Open the file, read each line,  and push that into an ArrayList. Afterwards, you can do whatever you want with that list.

And note: that is actually the point you should start with. Dont solve your whole problem at once. Slice it into smaller parts. Like: reading data from CSV ... has nothing to do with later processing the lines and printing those. You can write code that just takes an ArrayList, processes those and prints stuff. Which you can ... test on its own, as you can *hardcode* such lists in your code.

Comment: wouldnt i say linecount < numContest ?

I should have removed random and winnerDetails and printed all contestants (6 of them). How can I do that?

Comment: I do not intend to do your homework for you. You are already able to iterate the file content, and push that into a string. I suggest: put the code that parses and prints a SINGLE line into a distinct method. Then call that method when reading the file lines for examples. I know, this sounds complicated, but you learn programming by ... programming. It is really not that hard. Read about loops and arrays, and look what good books have to say about that. Dont ask others to do the heavy lifting for you.